# Calc 3: Calculate Work Done on Particle

Tags: vector-analysis

I've been working on this problem for a while and I'm pretty stuck. I tried it multiple different ways, by the last time I attempted it I realized that I hadn't converted kilometers to meters the entire time.

Anyway, the last approach I tried after doing the conversion was to integrate over the function from 7,000,000 to 8,300,000. I got a positive answer back, which I didn't think made sense given that the force would be opposing the movement, so I flipped signs. After integrating, I then multiplied the answer to the displacement (8,300,000 - 7,000,000) to get my final answer.

My logic was that integrating over the function would give me the total force, multiplying by the displacement would give me that total force over the distance which was the work. I don't understand what's wrong with this solution. This is a homework problem but at this point I've gotten it wrong too many times to get any points for it, I'm just itching to know how it's done.

[Picture of the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP5T7.png)

Comment: Remove the squares.

Comment: Tried it, it came back incorrect.

Comment: And don't multiply by 130000

Comment: Still coming back incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Smart Method**

The work done is equal to the change in potential energy. The potential of a gravitational field:

$$
v(\vec{r})=-\frac{GM}{\|\vec{r} \|}\ \phantom{aaaa}\dots(1)
$$

So the work done is
$$
m\Delta v=-\frac{GMm}{\|\vec{r}_1 \|}+\frac{GMm}{\|\vec{r}_2 \|}
$$
Where $\vec{r}_1$ is the initial radial vector and $\vec{r}_2$ the final.

This works as the potential is defined as the work done on a particle of unit mass in bringing it in from infinity to its final radial distance (which is why the sign in the potential is negative as the particle does work in moving from infinity). You can derive $(1)$ above by integrating force equation given in the question if you so desire.

Your answer in the attachment is wrong as you have the radial distances squared.

The gist of this can be found on the Wikipedia page on [Gravitational Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential)

**Brute Force and Ignorance method:**
$$
W=\int_{r=r_1}^{r_2}F\;dr=\int_{r=r_1}^{r_2}-\;\frac{GMm}{r^2}\;dr=\frac{GMm}{r_2}-\frac{GMm}{r_1}
$$

Comment: I tried your answer and unfortunately this also came back incorrect. Just to be clear, I inputted:

GMm/8,300,000 - GMm/7,000,000

System said this was incorrect. I understand that you integrated the given force equation, but wouldn't that give me total force rather than work? 

I also tried your answer multiplied by the displacement and it returned incorrect.

Comment: Try -2.2375e-8 GMm

Comment: Still returns incorrect.

Comment: Try a positive sign, the wording is slightly ambiguous about who/what is doing the work.

Comment: Tried the positive sign, still no dice.

Comment: That is a puzzle. The only other thing I can think of, and it is clutching at straws, is to leave the radii in km rather than converting to metres (it makes no sense to me why anyone would want it in that form, but may be worth a try)

Comment: @Bookie: Summing up the little bits of **force** times **displacement** over small intervals (of time) would give you the 'sum' of the little bits of **work done**. Always go back to the intended meaning of the integral. Same applies to integral of **velocity** with respect to **time**, giving **displacement**.

Comment: Hey Conrad, I was able to ask my professor about the question today in class and your method was correct. The only small thing that slipped through the cracks was that I had to flip the limits of integration when I flipped the sign.

Anyway, thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it.